# JavaScript using () in variable name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to optimize my code a little bit due to issues with it sometimes not working.
I am using 3 variables to set the state of 3 other variables. rather than wright the code out 3 times i wanted to use another variable (like (i)) to set which one is currently active, however i keep getting errors. I have tried looking for the answer but i can find any examples.

code:

```
var position(1) = a;
var position(2) = a;
var position3(2) = a;
var input(1) = 250;
var input(2) = 0;
var input(3) = 0;
var i = 1;
while (z <= 3) {

if (input(i) <= minvalue + range){
position(i) = a;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*2)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + range)+1){
position = b;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*3)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*2))+1){
position = c;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*4)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*3))+1){
position(i) = d;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*5)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*4))+1){
position(i) = e;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*6)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*5))+1){
position(i) = f;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*7)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*6))+1){
position(i) = g;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*8)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*7))+1){
position(i) = h;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*9)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*8))+1){
position(i) = i;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*10)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*9))+1){
position(i) = j;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*11)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*10))+1){
position(i) = k;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*12)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*11))+1){
position(i) = l;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*13)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*12))+1){
position(i) = m;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*14)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*13))+1){
position(i) = n;
}
if (input(i) <= (minvalue + (range*15)) && input(i) >= (minvalue + (range*14))+1){
position(i) = o;
}
if (input(i) >= maxvalue) {
    position(i) = p;
}
document.getElementById("slider" + (i)).style.top= position(i);
z = z+1;
}
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, `var position(1) = a` is invalid syntax. You're trying to assign something to a function call, which makes no sense. I am unsure what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: I was trying to set input(1) as a number and same for 2 and 3. The use i to  replace the 1 so i could run the same script on all 3 vars without needing 3 times as much code as shown. Basically the code was too long and the page finished loading before the script finished running so defaulted position to a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`variable_name()` is how you call a function.

If you want to have a collection of data then use an object (for arbitrary names) or an array (for an ordered list).

```
var position = [a, a, a];
var i = 0; // Note arrays are zero indexed
console.log(position[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you. It didn't even occur to me to use and array as a variable var.